# Missing forwarder Alert

Tags: splunk

DMC Alert - Missing forwarders alert not working properly.

We have provided the query as shown below and getting an output from different host servers and of different dates.I want only to alert when Universal forwarder stops working.

| inputlookup dmc_forwarder_assets | makemv delim=" " avg_tcp_kbps_sparkline | eval sum_kb = if (status == "missing", "N/A", sum_kb) | eval avg_tcp_kbps_sparkline = if (status == "missing", "N/A", avg_tcp_kbps_sparkline) | eval avg_tcp_kbps = if (status == "missing", "N/A", avg_tcp_kbps) | eval avg_tcp_eps = if (status == "missing", "N/A", avg_tcp_eps) | eval forwarder_type = case(forwarder_type == "full", "Heavy Forwarder", forwarder_type == "uf", "Universal Forwarder", forwarder_type == "lwf", "Light Forwarder", 1==1, forwarder_type) | search NOT [| inputlookup dmc_assets | dedup "servername" | rename "servername" as hostname | fields hostname] status=missing

Expected Result : Get the alert when splunk forwarder stops or failed to sent any logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the results of Universal Forwarders, you can try the query below

```
| inputlookup dmc_forwarder_assets | makemv delim=" " avg_tcp_kbps_sparkline | eval sum_kb = if (status == "missing", "N/A", sum_kb) | eval avg_tcp_kbps_sparkline = if (status == "missing", "N/A", avg_tcp_kbps_sparkline) | eval avg_tcp_kbps = if (status == "missing", "N/A", avg_tcp_kbps) | eval avg_tcp_eps = if (status == "missing", "N/A", avg_tcp_eps) | where forwarder_type="uf" | eval forwarder_type = "Universal Forwarder" | search NOT [| inputlookup dmc_assets | dedup "servername" | rename "servername" as hostname | fields hostname] status=missing
```